# Python execute threads by order

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, message-queue

I have the following code:

import threading

```
def send_to_server(lst):
    #Some logic to send the list to the server.


while 1:
    lst = []
    for i in range(1000):
        lst.append(i)
    task = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server,args(copy(lst),))
    task.start()
```

I have a few Questions:

1) The idea for using threads is because sending to server takes time and I want to continue 
generating the data without any stop.

The problem with this code is that if I created thread #3 and its taking long time to process, 
By that time thread #4 will be started.
I want to assure that every list will be sent to server by the other I created it, means thread #3 will send to server the data before thread #4. 
I understand that I need to use a Queue, but I don't know exactly how.

2)Should I use copy of lst? or I can use lst as well, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do iterate through `range(1000)` instead of using it directly: `lst = range(1000)`?

Comment: @zondo idk thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Queue`, the threadsafe queue class in python. I imagine you want a thread to put things in the queue, and a thread to act on them serially like so:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=fill_q,args(q, lst))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=consume_q,args(q, lst))
t1.start()
t2.start()

def fill_q(q, lst):
    for elem in lst:
        q.put(elem)

def consume_q(q, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        send_to_server(q.get())
```

If you are interested in performance, you may want to read up on the `GIL` in python, here https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: It looks like something that might work.
the fill_q will work with an infinite loop, while consume_q will work only if queue is not empty, how to check this efficiently?

Also, can you explain more about `GIL`?